# Click Listeners in Loop - Array and Closure

Tags: google-maps-api-3, closures, clicklistener

I realise I'm treading on thin ice opening another closure issue, but I have searched and can't find an answer to my issue. I have a Google Maps API v3 page which generates two maps from one block of code - a small map centered on the user's current location and a larger map showing the whole area with the user's location marked where it is, center or not.  On top of the map is a rectangle layer consisting of 14 rectangles.  In order to generate the two maps, I have had to put the rectangles in a 2 dimensional array, rectangles[1] for 'map', and rectangles[2] for 'map2':

```
var rectangles = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];

rectangles[1][0]=new google.maps.Rectangle({
bounds:new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(a, b), new google.maps.LatLng(x, y)),
map:map,
fillColor:'red',
fillOpacity: 0.3,
strokeOpacity: 0,
url: 'http://example.com',
clickable: true
});

rectangles[2][0]=new google.maps.Rectangle({
bounds:new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(a, b), new google.maps.LatLng(x, y)),
map:map2,
fillColor:'red',
fillOpacity: 0.3,
strokeOpacity: 0,
url: 'http://example.com',
clickable: true
});
```

...and so on.  It all works fine and the two maps are displayed and the geolocation works.  Now I want to add a click listener for each rectangle but I'm not sure who to reference the array.  This is what I have now:

```
for ( i = 0; i < rectangles[1].length; i++ ){
google.maps.event.addListener(rectangles[1][i], 'click', function() {
window.location.href = this.url;
});
}
for ( x = 0; x < rectangles[2].length; x++ ){
google.maps.event.addListener(rectangles[2][x], 'click', function() {
window.location.href = this.url;
});
}
```

Which obviously won't work.  I have seen various solutions to the closure issue, but I'm not sure I'm even heading in the right direction in referencing the two arrays of rectangles - or if I even need to define two different sets of click listeners.  I'd be really grateful if someone could point me in the right direction - and sorry if this is just going over old ground that appears obvious.  There's always a new learner coming along who is trying hard to catch up.

Thanks.

Comment: Surely `rectangles` needs to be initialized with something like `var rectangles = [[],[],[],[],...];`, and populating the arrays should start with `rectangles[0][0]`? As the code stands, `rectangles[1][0] = ...` will throw an error.

Comment: I'm new to this array business and I started out along the lines you suggest and got stuck.  I can't swear that it's right, but he current code does actually work in as much as it correctly draws all the rectangles.  The only think that doesn't work is clicking on the rectangles and linking to the URL set in each rectangle's properties.  The curser recognises there's a link (it changes to a pointing finger instead of a hand), but nothing happens when I click.

Comment: In javascript and many other languages, arrays have an index origin of 0, not 1. I will post an answer to your question shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//First, set up `rectangles` as an array containing two arrays.
var rectangles = [];
rectangles[0] = [];
rectangles[1] = [];

//As `google.maps.Rectangle` doesn't accept a `url` option, 
//its url needs to be defined separately from the rectangle itself,
//but in such a way that the two are associated with each other.
//For this we can use a javascript plain object. 
rectangles[0][0] = {
    rect: new google.maps.Rectangle({
        bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(a, b), new google.maps.LatLng(x, y)),
        map: map,
        fillColor: 'red',
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        strokeOpacity: 0,
        clickable: true
    }),
    url: 'http://example.com'
};
rectangles[1][0] = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    ...
});
rectangles[0][1] = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    ...
});
rectangles[1][1] = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    ...
});
rectangles[0][2] = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    ...
});
rectangles[1][2] = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    ...
});

//Now to attach the click listeners.

//First we define a function that adds a click listener.
//By doing this in its own function, a closure is formed,
//trapping the formal variable `rectObj` and making `rectObj.url` 
//accessible to the listener when it is called in response to future clicks.
function addClickListener(rectObj) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(rectObj.rect, 'click', function() {
        window.location.href = rectObj.url;
    });
}

//Now, we can loop through the `rectangles` arrays, adding listeners.
for ( i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) {
    for ( j = 0; j < 14; j++ ) {
        if(rectangles[i][j]) {//safety
            addClickListener(rectangles[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're a legend.  Works perfectly! Thanks.  I hereby renounce everything bad I have ever previously said about beetroot.  Merry Christmas.

Comment: And thank you too, that's the best giggle I've had in a while. Merry Christmas.