# Event click to rectangle on google map V3

Tags: jquery, google-maps, events, google-maps-api-3, click

I have a map which users can draw some rectangles, after users draw it all rectangles they can **click** them to start some events, like show more information, call web services, change properties of rectangles and more.

I need to **add a click event listener** to each rectangle, I tried the follow code but it didn't work. I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907103/click-listeners-in-loop-array-and-closure#answer-13953112).

```
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.066611095611856,-69.33721108996582),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);


var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingControl: true,
      drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
        drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE]
      },
      rectangleOptions: {
          fillColor: '#0011aa',
          fillOpacity: 1,
          strokeWeight: 5,
          clickable: false,
          editable: true,
          zIndex: 1
        }
});

drawingManager.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'rectanglecomplete', function(rectangle) {
        /* DOES NOT WORK */
        google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'click', function() {
            console.log(rectangle);
        });
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Thanks in advcance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things. First, you need to make your rectangles clickable.

```
  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingControl: true,
      drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
        drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE]
      },
      rectangleOptions: {
          fillColor: '#0011aa',
          fillOpacity: 1,
          strokeWeight: 5,
          clickable: true,
          editable: true,
          zIndex: 1
        }
});
```

Second. While the drawing manager is drawing, all click listeners are suppressed. You need to set the drawing mode to null after rectangle completion.

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'rectanglecomplete', function(rectangle) {
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
         /* DOES WORK */
        google.maps.event.addListener(rectangle, 'click', function() {
            console.log(rectangle);
        });
  });
```

Comment: oh yes - `clickable: true`