# Click Listeners in Loop for rectangle array -- Closure

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, closures, clicklistener

My question is very similar to this post but the solution doesn't work for me for some reason --> [Click Listeners in Loop - Array and Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907103/click-listeners-in-loop-array-and-closure)

Users can click on google map api; I want to make rectangles of 2kmx2km wherever the user clicks, add these to a rectangle array, and add listeners to them for clicks. The rectangles show up and the rectangle array is populated, but the click listeners just. don't. work. I'm at my wit's end and have endlessly researched and tried various solutions; any help will be much appreciated!

```js
var SFLatLng = {lat: 37.7739, lng: -122.4312};
var map;
var rectangleArray = [];
var rectangleArraySize = 0;

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
         center: SFLatLng,
         zoom: 12,
         scaleControl: true,
    });
    doStuff();
} //end map init

function doStuff() {
      //make rectangle of size 2kmx2km on map click
      map.addListener('click', function(e) {      
   var bounds = calcBounds(e.latLng, new google.maps.Size(2000,2000));
   addRectangleToMap(bounds);
      });

     function addRectangleToMap(boundsObj) {
  rectangleArray[rectangleArraySize] = {
       rect: new google.maps.Rectangle({
   map: map,
                 bounds: boundsObj,
                 fillColor:'red',
                 fillOpacity: 0.3,
                 strokeOpacity: 0,
                 clickable: true,
                 zIndex: 1
    })
   };
   rectangleArraySize++;
     }

     function addClickListener(rectObj) {
         google.maps.event.addListener(rectObj.rect, 'click', function() {
              alert("clicked!")
         });
     }

     for (var i = 0; i < rectangleArray.length; i++ ) {       
          if(rectangleArray[i]) { //safety
              addClickListener(rectangleArray[i]);
          }       
     }
}

/** @this {google.maps.Rectangle} */
function calcBounds(center,size){
    //Calculates bounds ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `addClickListener` function on the rectangle.

```
function addRectangleToMap(boundsObj) {
  rectangleArray[rectangleArraySize] = {
      rect: new google.maps.Rectangle({
      map: map,
      bounds: boundsObj,
      fillColor:'red',
      fillOpacity: 0.3,
      strokeOpacity: 0,
      clickable: true,
      zIndex: 1
    })
  };
  addClickListener(rectangleArray[rectangleArraySize]);
  rectangleArraySize++;
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ayv5f9zq/5/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var SFLatLng = {
  lat: 37.7739,
  lng: -122.4312
};
var map;
var rectangleArray = [];
var rectangleArraySize = 0;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: SFLatLng,
      zoom: 12,
      scaleControl: true,
    });
    doStuff();
  } //end map init

function doStuff() {
  //make rectangle of size 2kmx2km on map click
  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    var bounds = calcBounds(e.latLng, new google.maps.Size(2000, 2000));
    addRectangleToMap(bounds);
  });

  function addRectangleToMap(boundsObj) {
    rectangleArray[rectangleArraySize] = {
      rect: new google.maps.Rectangle({
        map: map,
        bounds: boundsObj,
        fillColor: 'red',
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        strokeOpacity: 0,
        clickable: true,
        zIndex: 1
      })
    };
    addClickListener(rectangleArray[rectangleArraySize]);
    rectangleArraySize++;
  }

  function addClickListener(rectObj) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(rectObj.rect, 'click', function() {
      // alert("clicked!");
      infowindow.setContent("clicked:<br>" + this.getBounds().toUrlValue());
      infowindow.setPosition(this.getBounds().getCenter());
      infowindow.open(map);

    });
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < rectangleArray.length; i++) {
    if (rectangleArray[i]) { //safety
      addClickListener(rectangleArray[i]);
    }
  }
}

/** @this {google.maps.Rectangle} */

function calcBounds(center, size) {
  var obj = {
    south: 37.70339999999999,
    west: -122.52699999999999,
    north: 37.812,
    east: -122.3482,
    lat: 37.7749295,
    lng: -122.4194155
  };
  if (rectangleArray.length == 0) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(obj.south, obj.west), new google.maps.LatLng(obj.lat, obj.lng));
  } else {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(obj.lat, obj.lng), new google.maps.LatLng(obj.north, obj.east));
  }
  console.log(bounds.toUrlValue());
  //Calculates bounds ...
  return bounds;
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: You, sir, are the real MVP. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

do the   use [immediately-invoked-function-expression(IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) so,one can bind value of `rectObj` immediately.

```
function addClickListener(rectObj) {

    (function(rectObj) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(rectObj.rect, 'click', function() {
            alert("clicked!")
        });
    })(rectObj)
}
```